# Complex integral $1/(z+2)$ along circle with radius 3

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I want to compute the complex integral $$\int_{|z|=3}\frac{1}{z+2}dz$$
i tried to evaluate the integral by a series expansion and also to just calcualte it by the definition of the path integral but it didnt work for me 
thanks in advance

Comment: Could you include what you've tried? This is a rather standard exercise...

Comment: i tried the geomatric sum and and the first steps of the definition because i thought that there might be more to it than the definition

Comment: Saying what you tried is not the same as showing what you tried. Showing what you've tried allows us to better help you as well as avoids answers from telling you what you already know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $f(z)= 1/(z+2)$ has only one pole in $\mid z \mid\le 3$ which is a simple pole at $z= -2$. By residue theorem, we have

$\int_{|z|=3}\frac{1}{z+2}dz = 2\pi i Res(f,-2)$ and $Res(f,-2)=1$. So, $\int_{|z|=3}\frac{1}{z+2}dz = 2\pi i$.